# UITableViewController Bottom Static Cell Space

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, table-footer

I'm having a hard time removing the space at the bottom of a UITableViewController with static cells. I only have one section. I thought it was the tableview footer at first but now I'm thinking that it is just because the last cell's height isn't adjusting to be pinned to the bottom of the view. I'm still a little new to iOS and just getting stumped here. I'd appreciate some help and thanks in advance. (photo below).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using this: 
Set a zero height table footer view like so:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the response but I tried that too and nothing.